# Can the document.location.protocol value be changed in a WinRT webview?

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm currently having an issue with the WebView control used in a Universal WinRT app (Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1).

I currently load the following piece of JavaScript into the WebView using the `NatigateToString` method:

```xml
<html>
  <head>
      <base href='MY_BASE_URL'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        var idcomments_acct = 'MY_ACC_ID';
        var idcomments_post_id='POST_ID';
        var idcomments_post_url='POST_URL';
    </script>
    <span id='IDCommentsPostTitle' style='display:none'></span>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.intensedebate.com/js/genericCommentWrapperV2.js'></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the piece of code for the IntenseDebate generic install that can be found [here](http://support.intensedebate.com/generic-install/).

The issue is with this line of code in the referenced IntenseDebate code:

```
load_js(document.location.protocol+"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js")
```

This piece of code fails because `document.location.protocol` is set to `about:` in the WebView, leading to a 404 error on this call.

On the Android/iOS webviews simply setting the base URI to a `http:` or `https:` based address using their `loadDataWithBaseUrl` methods worked fine, but the WinRT WebView is missing a similar method. And setting the Base url in the HTML itself (like shown in the piece of code above) does work for resolving image url's and sortlike, but this method doens't change the document.location values.

Since I can't modify the referenced JS file and putting the above piece of HTML on a server isn't an option in this apps usecase, is there any way you can force the document.location.protocol to be a certain value in the WinRT webview? Or is there any other way to get this bit of HTML to work in a webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this. WebView doesn't provide any interface to override the document.location . If branching off of the protocol is a common pattern then this may be a good feature to request on http://wpdev.uservoice.com .

I'm not familiar enough with HTML/JavaScript best practices to say for sure, but most of the references I find searching for document.location.protocol warn against assuming that the protocol will always be http: or https. This may be something that IntenseDebate should fix.

That said, you may be able to get past this by injecting code into your page which finds the problem location in the DOM and changing it live. You can't change just the protocol, but you may be able to find where it is referenced and change that there. I assume it gets loaded into the commentScript.src from genericCommentWrapper2.php referenced in genericCommentWrapper2.cs and then added to the document's head.

Comment: Alright. I will look into contacting IntenseDebate about this issue then, see if they are able to fix that bit of code. Thanks for the information.